# The encryption button is not working on Galaxy S Duos

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I cannot encrypt my S Duos, it has an ICS 4.0.4 custom ROM with bloatware removed. When I'm trying to encrypt, the encryption button looks like it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You must set screen lock password first, not PIN. Then try to encrypt and your button will be enabled. Then follow instructions...